# Is it possible to change the originating IP address in a NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, ip, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to make an url request call using swift 2.2 but I would like, if possible, to change the IP address from where the call is made.

To be more specific: in my ios mobile app I want to make http request to a certain url but I want that every time the mobile app makes a call to send a different IP address as the originating IP address.

I searched several blogs/forums but I didn't find anything related.

Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT:

The code I am using is:

```
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { }
```

Comment: What did you use to load url?

Comment: That's not how networking works. The originating IP address is the IP address of the device.  This address is assigned to the device by the network; WiFi or Mobile carrier (The user can set a static IP address but it still has to be compatible with the network they are connected to)

Comment: @Lumialxk, please see my updated question.

Comment: @Paulw11, well from what I read this is possible in C#, so I was wondering if it is possible in swift as well.

Comment: If a device has multiple IP addresses then you can nominate one to be the source of a connection, but these IP addresses need to be already assigned to the computer; such as a wired and wireless connection or multiple IP addresses assigned to an adapter.  You can't just pick an arbitrary IP address to send from.  NSURLSession doesn't let you specify a source interface but GCDAsyncSocket does as it is a lower-level framework

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you for your answer. I'll give a try with GCDAsyncSocket.

Comment: @BogdanAndrei Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @AskP, unfortunately I didn't.